# Split audio stream to files by slice detection

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, audio-streaming, icecast

Im currently working on a project where I would need to split a live audio stream to singele files.

In this project I'm getting constantly a audio stream of something like an podcast and I would like to detect the single 'slices' and save them on audio files with incremented names.

I've found some solutions for audio files but not for live audio streams and I would really appreciate your help. Preferably would be Python, but other langauges are okey too.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FFMPEG to read a live audio stream and output the audio to files that are timestamped or contain an incremental filename.

Please see : [Segment Muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment)

A simple example would be

```
ffmpeg -i http://www.livestream.com:8000/streamtest -f segment -segment_time 1800 -reset_timestamps 1 output_%03d.mp3
```

This would generate 1800second (30min) files named output_001, output_002, etc.